# I want to spilt a string and then count the value of solumn in dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split, count

I have a column in a DataFrame called control stores:

[image]

I want to split the string with ';' delimiter and count the string. Also, in cases where there is NAN or 1 value then it should display count as 1.

I tried below code:

```
final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].str.split(';')[0].count('Control Stores')
```

But it is giving 0 as a result but should come as 6

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

```
final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].fillna("temp").str.split(';').map(len)
```

is what you are looking for.

`final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].fillna("temp")` will simply replace all NaN by a dummy entry ("temp" in this case). You then split `.str.split(';')` exactly like you did before.  At this point you have a  pandas Series where each item is a list. When you append `.map(len)` on the Series it will compute the len of each list.

does it help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a count without actually extracting the individual strings, you can simply count the occurrences of your delimter:

```
final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].str.count(";").fillna(0).add(1)
```

Comment: This should be the answer. But just move `fillna(0)` before `add(1)` so that the answer matches what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this:

```
final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].str.split(';')[0].count('Control Stores')
```

The **str.split()** method returns a list of strings. See details [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

In your second image you see the result of:

```
final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].str.split(';')[0]
```

being a list of strings.

The **list.count()** method counts the number of appearances of the given argument within the list. And your provided argument here is 'Control Stores' which is not present in that list. To count the length of a list or string, use the **len()** built-in, for instance:

```
len(final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].str.split(';')[0])
```

or to get the length of the first string in that list:

```
len(final_input_optimization['Control Stores'].str.split(';')[0][0])
```